# Counting lattice paths which use fixed steps but can end in different places

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, integer-lattices

Consider a lattice path where one starts at $(0,0)$ and can move only right or up in integer steps.  The total number of steps made is $4$, but the maximum steps in one direction $3$. How many paths exist?

I have two different ideas but I'm not sure which (if either) is correct. The first:
$$\frac{n!}{n-k!}=\frac{6!}{2!}$$ where $n$ is the number of different movement options ($3$ up and $3$ right) and $k$ is the number of spaces ($4$). From here there are three different scenarios:

$$(right, up): (3,1),(2,2),(1,3).$$

Considering each of these, the number of paths is given by: $$\frac{6!}{2!}\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{1}{i!(k-i)!}=\frac{6!}{2!}(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4})=\frac{6!\cdot7}{2!\cdot12}=\frac{7!}{4!}=210$$
which seems very high. Alternatively:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{4!}{i!(k-i)!}=14$$ which considers 4 different arrangements of each scenario (I think).

I think the second method is correct, but I don't really understand where my thinking fails in the first method. If anyone could provide intuition as to why it is wrong, that would be great.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "move" and what "maximum number of moves in one direction" means. Maybe be more precise and/or provide some examples of allowed and not allowed paths.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I'm trying to refer to a North-East lattice path with steps $S=\{ (0,1),(1,0) \}$.

Comment: That I got. But what are moves?

Comment: By moves I mean steps - I'll edit the question. Sorry for confusion

Comment: Assuming I go from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$ and then to $(0,3)$. Is this one step/move since the direction didn't change? Do you mean "maximum consecutive steps in one direction" or "maximum total steps in one direction"?

Comment: The maximum total steps in one direction is $3$. So altogether you can travel $4$ steps, but you cannot travel to $(4,0)$ or $(0,4)$. You can however travel to $(3,1)$, $(2,2)$ or $(1,3)$. Going to $(0, 3)$ is always $3$ steps (so no more in that direction are allowed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start with $(0,0)$ and in each step add $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$, going $4$ steps in total, there are $2^4=16$ possible paths. If you forbid path's where the $x$ or $y$ coordinate ends up above $3$, you have to subtract the two paths going either all 4 steps up or all 4 steps right. In total you have $16-2=14$ paths satisfying your condition.

---

In general, the number of paths ending in $(x,y)$ is given by $\binom{x+y}{x} = \binom{x+y}{y}$ since you are going $x+y$ steps and have to choose which of them are up and which are right. So the $16$ pathes split as
$$
\binom{0+4}{0} + \binom{1+3}{1} + \binom{2+2}{2} + \binom{3+1}{3} + \binom{4+0}{4} =1+4+6+4+1.
$$
So if you want to make $n$ steps in total, only allowing at most $k\le n$ in each direction you get
$$
\sum_{i=n-k}^{k} \binom{n}{i}.
$$

Comment: How does this generalise? Say we have $4$ steps and stop $x$ or $y$ going above $2$, preventing $(3,1),(4,0),(1,3),(0,4)$. We end up with a $2\times2$ North-East lattice for which there are 6 paths, but $2^{4}-4\neq6$

Comment: I updated my answer.